# Bootstrap CSS doesn't display in rails project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've downloaded the project files from the Treehouse Rails Developer course. Rails Development adventure, Stage 4 : Using `AJAX`. I managed to get the app working but my bootstrap styling does not display.

The bootstrap files are all in their respective folders.

Here's some code from my `application.css` :

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree

body {
padding-top: 40px;
}

.alert {
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

My `application.html.erb` does contain the stylesheet link tag :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

I'm running rails v 3.2.6 on OSX Mavericks

Thanks ahead of time for the assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out :

1. set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true` in `application.rb`
2. flush the asset pipeline cache by running rake `tmp:cache:clear`

Answer (score 2):

Your application.css file should like this:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .

body {
padding-top: 40px;
}

.alert {
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

The period is important - it means grab all of the stylesheets in the current directory.

Comment: Went ahead and changed that with no luck still. When I'm inspecting the page, I noticed that application.css and application.js are linked but I don't see bootstrap.css or any other css files in my stylesheets folder

Comment: Hmm... maybe try using a gem to install the files for you? Check out [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics?view=asciicast) by Ryan Bates. Add the gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' to your Gemfile (don't forget to bundle install), and run the command `rails g bootstrap:install`. From there you can compare what you have against what the gem installs for you. Also don't forget to try restarting your server when you change up your assets.